# My JSON and Javascript is not working with my form

Tags: javascript, html, json, database, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSON</title>
</head>
body>
<div id="form">
    <form onsubmit="formSave()" name="signup">
        <input type="text" name="username">
       <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="displayUid()">Display</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function formSave() {
    var uid = document.forms["signup"]["username"].value;
    var myUser = { "userid":uid };
    var idJSON = JSON.stringify(myUser);
    localStorage.setItem("testJSON", idJSON);
}
function displayUid() {
    var txt = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
    var usid = JSON.parse(txt);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = usid.userid;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where I went wrong in this, It is just a test file, to see if I can make a sign up page with code, but it seems as if it won't work, I just need some help with this, I just started learning JSON two days ago so this is new to me, but JavaScript isn't new, I am nervous to ask here, because it might be that I missed some quotes or just a Typo on my part, if you can help please do.

Thank you for your time,
    David

Comment: Not that it's related to your questions, but opening body tag is missing `<` ;)

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: The form, either it doesnt save or open

Comment: Tested your code and it worked (even with the broken body tag)

Comment: Then wtf, did you need to create an external json file, and if so what was it called @Dionei Miodutzki

Comment: Nope.. just copy pasted your code on a file and it worked in Google Chrome